# How to pass values between two pages in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

what is the best practice to pass values between **pages** in WPF?

thanks

Comment: I go through a few different methods to pass parameters in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12444817/200442). It goes over using query string parameters, constructor arguments and a few others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass values (parameters) between XAML pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444816/how-to-pass-values-parameters-between-xaml-pages)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your fixed point of reference is the Application object. You can store stuff in the Properties collection:

```
 string myText = (string)Application.Current.Properties["test"];
```

Or you can add any kind of data to your derived App class.

Comment: this approach risks your App object becoming a God object.

Comment: An Application object always is a God object. No problem, just add a Configuration property.

Answer (score 8):

Example variable name = DeptName

Declare the variable in App.xaml
i.e.

`public string DeptName { get; set; }`

assign the value in your page-1

```
(App.Current as App).DeptName = "test";
```

then call the value in your page-2

```
 string selected_dept = (App.Current as App).DeptName;
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably via the Model in an [MVVM architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Comment: But where do you store the model?  It's a good idea but just moves the problem around.

Comment: @Henk, a short answer to a short question. But designing an MVVM application is a big subject, the link kindly provided by Klaus in my answer is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

same as Windows Forms:

do not just use global variables or access page's controls from another page. if you have two pages which need to share the same object, e.g. `Student`, have a method like `SetStudent(Student student)` in your page or use a property so one page can pass the object Student using that method. You can also have the Get of course, if needed.