# How get one page values to another page WPF?

Tags: wpf

How to get one page texbox values to another page.

E.g:

I have two XAML page like "Employee.xmal" & "EmployeePersonal.xmal".

I would like to pass Employee.xmal texbox values to EmployeePersonal.xmal page.

Can you please help me to solve this issues.

Comment: How do you create the pages and what is the relationship between them?

Answer (score 0):

Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22381851/5533217

Example variable name = DeptName

Declare the variable in App.xaml i.e.

```
public string DeptName { get; set; }
```

assign the value in your page-1

```
(App.Current as App).DeptName = "test";
```

then call the value in your page-2

```
string selected_dept = (App.Current as App).DeptName;
```